# ¿Cuál es el orden de ejecución de las clases heredadas en POO?

Tags: typescript, poo

Tengo el siguiente código conceptual en Typescript:

```ts
abstract class Padre{
    protected config = {
       propPadre: `Inicial padre`
    };
    constructor(
        pConfig?: Partial<Padre["config"]>
    ) {
        this.setConfig(pConfig);
    }
    protected override setConfig(
        pConfig: Partial<Padre["config"]>
    ){
        if (typeof pConfig != "object") return; 
        this.config.propPadre = pConfig.propPadre;
    }
}
class Hijo extends Padre{
    protected override config = {
       propPadre: `Inicial padre`,
       propHijo: `Inicial hijo`
    };
    constructor(
        pConfig?: Partial<Hijo["config"]>
    ) {  
        super(pConfig);
    }
    protected override setConfig(
        pConfig: Partial<Hijo["config"]>
    ){
        if (typeof pConfig != "object") return; 
        super.setConfig(pConfig);
        this.config.propHijo = pConfig.propHijo;
    }
}
//instancio:
const instancia = new Hijo({
    propHijo: "nuevo hijo",
    propPadre: "nuevo padre",
});
```

La expectativa de la instancia debería ser (incluso chat-GPT indica que esta debe ser la salida):

```
instancia.propHijo; // "nuevo hijo"
instancia.propPadre; // "nuevo padre"
```

La realidad es:

```
instancia.propHijo; // "Inicial hijo"
instancia.propPadre; // "Inicial padre"
```

retomando las bases de POO tengo entendido que el orden de ejecución sería:

-> Propiedades estáticas `Hijo`

-> Propiedades dinámicas `Hijo`

-> Constructor Clase `Hijo`

-> Super()  en `Hijo`

-> Propiedades estáticas `Padre`

-> Propiedades dinámicas `Padre`

-> Constructor Clase `Padre`

-> Super()  en `Padre`

-> setConfig() `Hijo` // se llama desde el padre pero por jerarquía se ejecuta el del hijo

-> setConfig() `Padre`

Sin embargo una vez instanciada la clase `Hijo` con los resultados pareciera que no sigue este orden, ¿qué hay malo en mi análisis?

Comment: @padaleiana ok listo una vez pegado es con el atajo [  ctrl+k  ] para indentarlo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En esencia primero se crea todo lo definido en el padre y luego todo lo del hijo pisa a lo del padre entonces el orden en el que suceden las cosas es:

1. Propiedades Padre
2. Constructor Padre
3. setConfig Padre
4. Propiedades hijo reemplazan a Propiedades Padre si se llaman igual, caso contrario se crean propiedades nuevas de hijo
5. Constructor Hijo. Se ejecuta todo lo que esta después de `super(...)`

en conclusión, debes agregar `setConfig` en el constructor del Hijo después de `super(...)`

código de ejemplo

```
class PersonConfig {
    [k:string]:any;
}

class Padre{
    protected config: PersonConfig = {
       propPadre: `Inicial padre`
    };
    constructor(
        pConfig: PersonConfig
    ) {
        this.setConfig(pConfig);
    }
    protected setConfig(
        pConfig: PersonConfig
    ){
        if (typeof pConfig != "object") return; 
        this.config.propPadre = pConfig.propPadre;
    }
}
class Hijo extends Padre {
    protected config: PersonConfig = {
       propPadre: `Inicial padre`,
       propHijo: `Inicial hijo`
    };
    constructor(
        pConfig: PersonConfig
    ) {  
        super(pConfig);
        this.setConfig(pConfig);
    }
    protected setConfig(
        pConfig: Partial<Hijo["config"]>
    ){
        if (typeof pConfig != "object") return; 
        super.setConfig(pConfig);
        this.config.propHijo = pConfig.propHijo;
    }
}
//instancio:
const instancia = new Hijo({
    propHijo: "nuevo hijo",
    propPadre: "nuevo padre",
});

console.log(instancia)
```

PD: Agregué una clase para la configuración de la "Persona" porque el intellisense no me dejaba usar la nomenclatura que tu tienes

PD2: el usar la palabra clave "override" es para interface, en class simplemente le pones el mismo nombre que en el padre y se sobre escribe

Con respecto a lo que dices de Partial<>, eso si me lo reconoce son otras cosas las que no me reconoce, te dejo un link a la herramienta online que use

[typescript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsAJlApgN4CwAUAhQgA5QD2E%208%20OStAdgGYCWA5ggLwIS5SpRq0q2PPgBcCAAYBJNl1hdgyargLyyogL4BuPZVjtIUAK7xaUABQnRFKgGF23HgH452KBHXIADxSBADaAERmnLzhALoAfI4IAJRCSaIQABZcYAB0YPgQbtE8dq7uvMnGIhT6SeIMTCy0AG74UFBcOPgIBUUVpelixR4%20wH4Bwdr4EVEecYk1KcJOlFwcCHYQAJ5U%20LQb5SUIAISC4bQgAFaMEOGpBBCWUGyGCEMUWTm5c7y54pJpgJqCM-gCQvhqgYyHVSCg0BgABJcK60BD4AAeDDYOAwEJWYjojQYzTaHS6PV%20fEEBKc4OmciUKjUGi00nkABoPgDkajGcpVAEENlUbolkYklELNYILYHEtREcPN4sON-BpArzaLMBgskqlCBQPr1LHt7ErKlDKLDFUTbswEK12p1ur1CqDBgrhgMxhMNVqdSU9UtkrSnOtNjs9gcQQNTudLjd4PcEI9nq93l6KGBTe18u6BmUPVVjV88lT-nQqFrgRaeJWJFqrbUYWQAPRtrhsSDANhqWgyMhSxBdnt99TAtj4ADuCC1djDPJRA4Q4TYlnwLTRIto4S5S3p0jka43W7ZBD3MKqQA)

otra cosa, lo que yo suelo hacer en constructor es asignar todas las propiedades ahí sin usar otro método lo que hace las cosas más fáciles en algunas situaciones

```
class Padre {
  ...
  // propiedades
  ...

  constructor(fields?: Partial<Padre>) {
     Object.assign(this, fields);
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, aclaraciones, estoy de acuerdo en lo que dices <se crea todo lo del padre primero> pero está una duda. Tenia entendido que al asignar el valor  (en este caso de `config`) directamente en la definición de la propiedad esta se ejecutaba primero (y que esa era la diferencia con asignarla el valor dentro del constructor), por esta razón la asignación (tanto en `Padre` como en `Hijo`) se hace antes que el constructor; (teniendo en cuenta lo que dices que el `config` de `Hijo` es el que se mantendrá), pero en ejecución es como si ignorar la sobreescritura de `config` de `Hijo`.

Comment: en cuanto a tu solución, también pensé en ella y es viable solo que si te das cuenta en el `setConfig()` de `Hijo` se llama con `super` a la de `Padre` entonces estaria ejecutando 2 o mas veces la misma reasignacion, ahi toca quitar ese llamado a `super` pero me tocaria garantizar en todas las subclases que ese método `setConfig()` este sobreescrito y llamado siempre

Comment: en cuanto a `override` es para recordarme a mi mismo que eso es sobreescrito, me gustaria saber por que el intellisense no te lo reconoció, `<Partial<>>` es una utilidad muy vieja en typescript

Comment: Cuando haces herencia todo lo del "hijo" se ejecuta después porque no tiene sentido que una versión obsoleta llámese el "padre" sobre escriba a la versión actualizada. Esto es exclusivo de la herencia, en caso de una clase cualquiera primero se asignan las propiedades y después se ejecuta el constructor